# Debug a Grails 3.x application

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I am trying to debug a Grails 3.x application using `grails run-app --debug-fork`. But when the application starts it does not wait for the debugger to attach. Any solution on how to debug a Grails 3.x application?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please use the `--debug-jvm` flag.
For example: `grails --debug-jvm run-app`

Comment: Is there a way to use this option with an IDE?

Comment: @IcedDante You can easily use it in any IDE by configuring the run setup by simply writing `--debug-jvm` in the command fields. All standard IDEs support additional command line arguments.

Comment: this opens the interactive console, doesn't run the app

Answer (score 11):

In IntelliJ you can right click the Gradle task `bootRun` and select Debug.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to directly run the [`Application`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#applicationClass) class located in `grails-app/init`. It has a `static void main` and be run as a regular application. You can run it directly from your IDE with a debug profile.

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1, I create two configurations. This allows me to make solid use of all the context menus, etc. that IntelliJ IDEA offers. Here's how:

1. The first configuration is a "Run" configuration. Edit the default
   configuration and in the "Command Line" field, enter 
   `run-app --debug-jvm`
2. The second configuration is a "Remote" configuration. On the "Run/Debug" dialog, click the + symbol and select "Remote" from the
   list. Name it "Debug" and save.
3. Select your "Run" config from the config dropdown at the top and then click the green arrow to run the app. Monitor the console
   output until you see the message 
   `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`.
4. Select the remote debug profile you created in step 2 and click the debug button. In a few moments the console output will say 
   `Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development`.

Success!

Comment: My Project is running fine but if i try to debug as steps provide above i got this error ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.

Comment: in gradle file I added this 
buildscript->dependencies->
classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29' now it works :)